# count unique values of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, bigdata

Suppose I have data.frame like this:

```
a b 1
b c 2
c e 3
d a 4
```

I was trying to count unique values of first two columns, so the result should be `5` which stands for `a b c d e`

But my problem is my data is so big about 7,000,000 rows, so I want to append the second column of rows into the first one. But I only know how to append one row at a time so anyone has ideas about how to append the whole column into the first one? Or do you have better ideas on solving this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `unlist` with `unique`

```
length(unique(unlist(df1[1:2])))
#[1] 5
```

Or transpose the dataset i.e. after subsetting the first 2 columns, concatenate it to `vector`, get the `unique` elements and find the `length`

```
length(unique(c(t(df1[-3]))))
#[1] 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), v2 = c("b", "c", "e", 
"a"), v3 = 1:4), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a compact alternative, you can also use the set function `union`:

```
length(with(df1, union(v1, v2)))
[1] 5
```

The underlying code to `union` is nearly identical to @akrun's code which can be seen typing the function without the parentheses:

```
union
function (x, y) 
unique(c(as.vector(x), as.vector(y)))
<bytecode: 0x41f0790>
<environment: namespace:base>
```